# What is the difference between plt.close() and plt.close(fig)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have searched everywhere for this question, but I can't seem to figure it out...In some places, plt.close(fig) is referenced and in other places plt.close() is referenced. Does the `fig` inside really make a difference. If so, what is it? Was it previously assigned or is it assigned by default when matplotlib.pyplot is imported into program. I just want to know because every single time I come across that I don't really know what to try.

Comment: This is well explained in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.close.html). If no argument is given, the *current* figure is closed. Otherwise, the given figure is closed

Comment: `plt.close(fig)` closes the figure `fig`. `plt.close("all")` closes *all* open figures.

Comment: Ok, thanks! That definitely helped me.